# Extract data between two points in a text file

Tags: windows, linux

How would it be possible to extract data between two points in a text file?

E.g.

```
Reply: [200/OK] bytes=29086 time=583ms
```

The value between "time=" and "ms"

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -n 's/.*time=\(.*\)ms/\1/p' < logfile
```

This sets up a regular expression that captures everything between the `time=` and `ms` into the first capture group (which is referred to on the right-hand-side as `\1`) and prints it.

Comment: This removes the "time" and "ms", sorry if I wasn't clear, but I would like to basically  want to remove everything apart from the value inbetween them

Comment: @Graham: Did you type in the `.*` before the `time`? Did you type in the `-n`? Both are vital. (Also put in a `.*` after the `ms` if there is expected to be any output after that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d= -f3 filename | grep -o '^[0-9]\+'
```