# Extracting data from a text file using awk

Tags: linux, sed, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract data between two points in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997462/extract-data-between-two-points-in-a-text-file)

For example:

```
Reply: [200/OK] bytes=29086 time=583ms
```

I would want to extract the value between "time=" and "ms"

**Expected Result:**

"583"

Answer (score 9):

I would use sed for that, but since you ask for awk:

```
echo "Reply: [200/OK] bytes=29086 time=583ms" | awk -F'time=|ms' '{print $2}'
```

The `-F` defines extended regexp for field separator. So we define that "time=" or "ms" separates the fields, and then print second field.

using sed, it would be:

```
echo "Reply: [200/OK] bytes=29086 time=583ms" | sed 's/.*time=\([0-9]*\)ms.*/\1/'
```

Comment: Why print second capture group? Curious, not criticizing.

Comment: @kevlar1818: assuming you ask about $2 in awk example: because $1 will be before first separator, so before "time=". We need after it.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see what's its doing now. Thanks! Handy option.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Reply: [200/OK] bytes=29086 time=583ms" | sed "s/.*time=\(.*\)ms/\1/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugly but works:

```
$ echo "Reply: [200/OK] bytes=29086 time=583ms" | 
    awk '{print $4'} | sed -e 's/[a-z=]//g'
583
```

Or without `sed`:

```
$ echo "Reply: [200/OK] bytes=29086 time=583ms" | 
    awk '{ split($4,a,"="); gsub(/ms/,"", a[2]); print a[2] }'
583
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
printf "Reply: [200/OK] bytes=29086 time=583ms\n" \
| awk '/^Reply:/{sub(/^.*time=/,"",$0) ;sub(/ms$/,"",$0); print $0}'
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.