# Retrieve text from predictable toml files and output as CSV

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, toml

I have some predictable `.toml` files with content structure like:

```
key1 = "someID"
key2 = "someVersionNumber"
key3 = "someTag"
key4 = "someOtherTag"
key5 = [] #empty array, sometimes contains strings
key6 = "long text"
key7 = "more text"
key8 = """
- text
- more text
- so much text
"""
```

I want to transform it to CSV like this:

```
"key1","key2","key3","key4","key5","key6","key7","key8"
"someID","someVersionNumber","someTag","someOtherTag","","long text","more text", "- text- more text- so much text"
```

Can I do this with a few lines of bash commands?

What about if I want to combine all the lines of CSV into one, e.g.

```
"key1","key2","key3","key4","key5","key6","key7","key8"
"someID","someVersionNumber","someTag","someOtherTag","","long text","more text", "- text- more text- so much text"
"someID","someVersionNumber","someTag","someOtherTag","","long text","more text", "- text- more text- so much text"
"someID","someVersionNumber","someTag","someOtherTag","","long text","more text", "- text- more text- so much text"
```

...i.e. the output would be one line of CSV per `.toml` file plus the header at the top (always the same CSV header and number of columns since the `.toml` files are predictable).

Am I looking at sed, awk, or something even simpler? I have looked at some related questions but feel I must be missing something as I'm getting too much functionality:

[Extract data between two points in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997462/extract-data-between-two-points-in-a-text-file)

[Parsing json with awk/sed in bash to get key value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908554/parsing-json-with-awk-sed-in-bash-to-get-key-value-pair?r=searchresults)

Comment: The question is a bit on the broad side IMO but to give a rough outline : Have a way to produce the header, either extracting it from a file or just simply hardcoding it. Call that, write result to file. Have something that transforms a .toml file to a CSV data line. The general case could simply be done with `cut -d' ' -f3` but you'll also need to handle arrays and multiline values. Call that for each .toml file using for with a glob and append to output file

Comment: Can we assume that header `"key1","key2","key3","key4","key5","key6","key7","key8"` beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were only one input file, I'd go with a Perl one-liner. Unfortunately, it comes out rather complex:

```
perl -pe 'if(/"""/&&s/"""/"/.../"""/&&s/"""/"\n/){s/[\n\r]//;};if(/ = \[([^]]*)]/){$r=$1eq""?"\"\"":$1=~s/"\s*,\s*"/ /gr;s/ = \[([^]]*)]/ = $r/};s/"\s*#[^"\n]*$/"/' one.toml | perl -ne 'if(/^([^"]+) = "(.*)"/){push@k,$1;push@v,"\"$2\""}END{print((join",",@k),"\n",join",",@v)}'
```

Things only get worse if we need to operate on multiple (`*`) files at once:

```
perl -ne 'if(/"""/&&s/"""/"/.../"""/&&s/"""/"\n/){s/[\n\r]//;};if(/ = \[([^]]*)]/){$r=$1eq""?"\"\"":$1=~s/"\s*,\s*"/ /gr;s/ = \[([^]]*)]/ = $r/};s/"\s*#[^"\n]*$/"/;print;print"-\n"if eof' *.toml | perl -ne 'if(/^-$/){push@o,join",",@k if scalar@o==0;push@o,join",",@v;@k=@v=()};if(/^([^"]+) = "(.*)"/){push@k,$1;push@v,"\"$2\""}END{print join"\n",@o}'
```

These two factors call for a structured script. Here it is in Perl, but the same can be done in Python or any language you're comfortable with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings; my @output;

foreach my $filename (@ARGV) {
    my $content, my @lines, my $replace, my @keys, my @values;
    open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $filename or die "Could not open $filename: $!";
    {local $/; $content = <$fh>;}
    $content =~ s/"""([^"]*)"""/'"' . $1=~s#[\r\n]##rg . '"'/ge;
    @lines = split (/[\r\n]/, $content);
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        if ($line =~ m/ = \[([^]]*)]/) {
            $replace = $1 eq "" ? '""' : $1 =~ s/"\s*,\s*"/ /gr;
            $line =~ s/ = \[([^]]*)]/ = $replace/
        }
        $line =~ s/"\s*#[^"]*$/"/;
        $line =~ m/^([^"]+) = "(.*)"/;
        push @keys, $1;
        push @values, '"' . $2 . '"'
    }
    push @output, join ",", @keys if scalar @output == 0;
    push @output, join ",", @values
}
print join "\n", @output
```

**Notes:**

Much of the complexity is due to having to deal with arrays (!), comments and multiline strings. Some preprocessing is needed for each, and that's what takes up most of the solution length. Moreover, additional information would be needed about possible corner cases and how to deal with them (e.g. how to fit an array of strings in a CSV). All of this only underlines the importance of input data quality and consistence. The proposed solution is by no means complete or robust, as it does make several assumptions about input data and the desired output format. Here's how I tackled the mentioned issues:

- **values** are expected to be strings only, as they are in the posted sample file. The script does not handle numbers, dates and booleans.
- **arrays** can be either empty `[]` or arrays of strings `["my", "array"]`. In the absence of a clear specification by the OP, they translate to a single string that is the concatenation of all element strings. No line breaks are allowed within an array, nor can an array contain other arrays.
- **comments** are handled only if they come inline after a string value. No comment-only lines.
- **indentation**, **blank lines** and **section headers** are not handled

---

**Test run:**

```
$ perl toml-to-csv.pl *.toml
"someID1","someVersionNumber1","someTag1","someOtherTag1","","long text1","more text1","- text- more text- so much text"
"someID2","someVersionNumber2","someTag2","someOtherTag2","Array","long text2","more text2","- text- more text- so much text"
"someID3","someVersionNumber3","someTag3","someOtherTag3","My array","long text3","more text3","- text- more text- so much text"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
{
    sub(/[[:space:]]*#[^"]*$/,"")
    key = val = $0
}

sub(/^[[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]+=[[:space:]]+/,"",val) {
    sub(/[[:space:]]+.*/,"",key)
    keys[++numKeys] = key
    gsub(/^("""|\[])$|^"|"$/,"",val)
    vals[numKeys] = val
}

/^-[[:space:]]+/ {
    vals[numKeys] = vals[numKeys] val
}

/^"""$/ {
    if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
        for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
            printf "\"%s\"%s", keys[keyNr], (keyNr<numKeys ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        printf "\"%s\"%s", vals[keyNr], (keyNr<numKeys ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
"key1","key2","key3","key4","key5","key6","key7","key8"
"someID","someVersionNumber","someTag","someOtherTag","","long text","more text","- text- more text- so much text"
```

Replace `file` with the list of your input files.

The regexp I'm using in `sub(/[[:space:]]*#[^"]*$/,"")` to remove comments that start with `#` means that you can't have a double quote in a comment. I did that to protect against changing `#` appearing within data strings. Feel free to figure out a better regexp or other approach to handle your comments.

Comment: would it have made things simpler if i'd used totally random keynames instead of (apparently) ordered names (with an index)?

Comment: No, it makes no difference. The script would be written the same way and will work no matter what the key values are.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine with the OP's single input file. However, when I tried to elaborate multiple [files](https://pastebin.com/5ynwFeTg) at once, the [output](https://pastebin.com/HVGQEyDF) doesn't look quite right. Moreover, could you please explain your handling of arrays? I get `"["My", "array"]"` which doesn't make much sense to me as a CSV value.

Answer (score 1):

"For the record" (as the question is almost three years old by now) and future readers: By using the command-line tool `tomlq`, which is a part of https://github.com/kislyuk/yq, this task becomes as simple as

```sh
tomlq -r 'map(arrays |= join(" ") | gsub("\n"; "")) | @csv' *.toml
```

`tomlq` basically transforms its input into JSON, and then applies a [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) filter on it. The one used above acts as follows:

- `map(…)` applies its subfilter to each element of its input structure (each of the "keys" in this case)
- `arrays |= join(" ")` replaces arrays by joining their elements using a space as glue (hits "key5")
- `gsub("\n"; "")` replaces any newline character with nothing (effectively deleting them)
- `@csv` transforms the result into a CSV-formatted line (using quotes and, if necessary, escapes)

This solution follows the interpretations of the other answers wrt transforming an array into a string by concatenating its elements separated by a space character (defined as parameter to the `join` function), and to eliminate newlines without replacement (defined as second parameter to the `gsub` function) in both arrays and strings, as this function is applied after the conversion from arrays to strings.

That said, this filter expects the values to be either strings or arrays. However, as the `@csv` builtin also handles correctly numbers and booleans, the filter could easily be adapted to support them by limiting the string substitution `gsub` to be applied only to strings by prepending `strings |=` (just like the conversion of arrays to strings using `join` is limited to arrays using `arrays |=`). Only the handling of dates would be more difficult to implement as there is no direct representation of them in JSON and CSV (one would have to convert them to strings beforehand).

The values are processed in order of their appearance in the source file and regardless of the actual key names. Thus, any different ordering between two files will be passed on as is, and not be matched wrt to a key ordering, which, however, could also be taken care of easily by explicitly referencing the key names in the implementation (e.g. `[.key1, .key7, .key4 ] | …`).

Generating a CSV header line from the key names can also be accomplished easily by prepending the whole filter with `keys_unsorted,`. The comma in it would make it another record to which `@csv` is being applied at the end. However, as the overall purpose is to transform the contents of multiple `.toml` files but supposedly produce only one CSV header, the easiest way would be to outsource it into its own filter, which would then be applied to only one input file (the other way using one filter for all would also be possible, though).

```sh
tomlq -r 'keys_unsorted | @csv' first.toml
```